# Using enumitem inside mdframed

Tags: lists, enumitem, mdframed

I tried to use `enumitem`s within `mdframed` as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\pitem}[1]{{\item {\small #1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}

\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{70}]
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\end{itemize}
\hrule
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{80}]
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\end{itemize}
\hrule
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{90}]
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\end{itemize}
\hrule
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{212}]
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\end{itemize}

\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

but striangly (at least to me), the first two sets of `itemize` will NOT work properly, but from the third set, everything is fine.

[image]

Comment: @lockstep: I suggest the tag `macro` ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem doesn't belong to any of your tagged packages. It belongs to your definition of `pitem`. You can't put `item in an extra group.

Instead use:

```
\newcommand{\pitem}[1]{\item {\small #1}}
```

Here the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\pitem}[1]{\item {\small #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}

\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{70}]
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\end{itemize}
\hrule
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{80}]
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\end{itemize}
\hrule
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{90}]
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\end{itemize}
\hrule
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{212}]
\pitem{Item}
\pitem{Item}
\end{itemize}

\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect! I was struggling with this for hours and had no clue where is the source :)

Comment: @Ali: If it works please accept my answer ;-) One unanswered question less which is tagged with `mdframed` ;-)

Comment: Actually I tried to do this, but stackexchange does not allow accepting answer before 10-15min of the question date. Probably, SE had no idea of super-quick supporters like you ;) Your support is as perfect as your work on `mdframed`. This is the reason that I preferred to use `mdframed` instead of standard `section`. Thanks again for your support and excellent work!